# Querying SQL table column of type JSON from Python takes forever?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, json

I am using the mysql.connector package in Python in order to query some data from my database.

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="host",
    user="usr",
    password="pw"
)


mycursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)

command = "SELECT data FROM schema.`table`"

mycursor.execute(command)
fetchy = mycursor.fetchone()
print(fetchy)

connection.close()
```

The column "data" is of type JSON. This command takes multiple minutes to run for a single row. I have several thousand rows. If I select from a different non-json column, I have no problem returning data instantly, but with this column it is taking absurdly long. It does not take this long when querying from MySQL workbench.

I'm wondering if there is an issue with my machine or if this is normal.

Is there a reason for this? Or anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Pretty hard to answer without the database. Ideally we'd like a [mre]. Can you give us instructions to reproduce this?

Comment: Could you try to remove buffered=True or ad LIMIT 0, 1

Comment: Where is the DB, Is it local or on the internet somewhere? How big is the "json" column?  It's possible that its slow because you are just submitted a giant request to a remote server.

Comment: The database is hosted remotely on company servers. Essentially it's just several columns, the first being "data" which holds a large piece of JSON. The rest are strings. All columns are taking a substantial amount of time to process, but JSON is taking by far the longest. I'm not sure why this is because I wasn't having this problem a few weeks ago

Comment: @MichałDarowny Removing buffered=True seems to have done the trick. If you want to put that as an answer to this question I'll accept it

Comment: out of curiosity, try running the following command `SELECT sum(char_length(COLUMN_NAME)) FROM TABLE_NAME` it should give you the size of the column in bytes

Comment: @Nullman it returned 2639015261. Is that particularly high for this kind of operation?

Comment: @Nullman it takes about 1-2 seconds to return a single line of data. Is that expected? And is there any way to speed it up? Because my dataset has about 9000 rows.

Comment: Thats 2.4 GIGABYTES, of course it takes some time to run!

Comment: @Nullman so for me to get through every item (9000 rows) in the table I can expect it to take a little over 2 hours?

Comment: it depends on 3 major factors: your internet speed, the sql servers internet speed and the sql server current load.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help